# Strange value in Searchrec.Attr (Value: 48)

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I'm using TSearchRec to map directories, but one specific directory the `Attr` is return decimal 48 hex 30.

In `SysUtils` unit there are the following values:

```
{ File attribute constants }

  faReadOnly  = $00000001 platform;
  faHidden    = $00000002 platform;
  faSysFile   = $00000004 platform;
  faVolumeID  = $00000008 platform;
  faDirectory = $00000010;
  faArchive   = $00000020 platform;
  faSymLink   = $00000040 platform;
  faAnyFile   = $0000003F;
```

In this list doesn't have this value. So, how can i solve this "problem"?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are flags that can be combined with bitwise OR. So `$30` is `faDirectory or faArchive`.

The reason that the flags can be combined is that the flags (largely) represent independent attributes of the file system object. A file system object can have none, one, or many of these attributes.

Comment: Thank you very much! It works fine! But i have a question: Why i need combine this flags if i have a directory and not a archive? If you know please comment here for me? Thanks!

Comment: `faArchive` doesn not indicate that an object is an "archive". It is a flag to indicate that the object has been archived. It is used by backup programs.  A more obvious example would be a file that is both read only and hidden. That would be `faReadOnly or faHidden`. Essentially a file system object can have multiple of these objects. These are not mutually exclusive.